# How to use the onPause method inside an Adapter to stop ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-lifecycle, exoplayer2.x

I have an Exoplayer inside a RecyclerView. When we use the Exoplayer within an Activity, we can use onPause and onResume to stop/resume the player:

```
//pause player
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(simpleExoPlayer != null) {
        positionExo = simpleExoPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    }
    super.onPause();
}

//resume player
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(simpleExoPlayer != null) {
        simpleExoPlayer.seekTo(positionExo);
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
}
```

How to do this inside an adapter?

Comment: based on scroll state and visibility of that particular item you can achieve pause and resume

Comment: @Madhur can you explain what you mean? I am having the same problem. Want to pause ExoPlayer in Adapter.